# What are the semantics of assigning restrict pointer to a non-restrict one?

Tags: c, language-lawyer, restrict-qualifier

Is the following hypothetical code correct (are the assumptions in comments hold)? Or does it have UB?

```
#define N 1 // what if it's 0?

void foo(int *x, int * restrict y) {
  *x = 42;
  *y = 0;
  // compiler can assume *x is still 42.
  {
    int *a = y + N;
    *a = 123;
    // compiler can no longer assume *x is 42.
  } // does the new scope matter in this case?
}
```

Comment: I don't see how manipulating `y` pointer affects the `x`? Or you forgot to tell about some special way to call this function?

Comment: Don't forget, that in C pointer arithmetic is only allowed when the result is within the *same object*.

Comment: @EugeneSh.but AFAIK for arrays, `restrict` applies to underlying objects and not the whole array (i.e. it's okay to have two restrict pointers to the same array as long as their ranges never overlap).
I'm not sure what you mean by your first comment. Without the restrict qualifier, after `*y = 0` the compiler wouldn't know whether *x was changed (if `x == y` for example).

Comment: Why do you want to abuse the promise given to the compiler? Only use restrict when it makes sense.

Comment: @DanM. Well, you can look at the standard `memcpy` definition, it is using `restrict` which is applied to the whole arrays.

Comment: @P__J__ why do you accuse me of abuse? I'm clarifying what exactly `restrict` promises to the compiler, in particular the interaction between restrict-qualified and non-qualified pointers derived from them.

Comment: it is the same abuse as here https://godbolt.org/z/Gn7P7T

Comment: @EugeneSh. where is that? Standard memcpy definition only has restrict qualifiers and nothing else. The restrict qualifiers formal definition is quite hard to parse (hence the question), but the given example supports that something like `char *d, memcpy(d, d + 50, 25)` is valid. So array is not considered as a single object for the purposes of the "overlapping object", rather it's individual elements. At least that's the impression that I've got.

Comment: @P__J__ what is the godbolt link supposed to prove? This question is about how does the standard define the semantics for the hypothetical piece of code (see language-lawyer tag), not whether it's good idea to write such code in the first place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> `// compiler can no longer assume *x is 42.`

I see no basis for this assertion.

> `// does the new scope matter in this case?`

No. The rules for restrict cover a block **B** that, for a restrict-qualified pointer declared in function parameters, is the block that defines the function. This block within that block **B** is part of **B**.

The definition of `restrict` is given in C 2018 6.7.3.1. Paragraph 1 says:

> Let **D** be a declaration of an ordinary identifier that provides a means of designating an object **P** as a restrict-qualified pointer to type **T**.

`int * restrict y` is a declaration **D** of the ordinary identifier “`y`”, and `y` designates an object **P** that is a restrict-qualified pointer to an `int` (type **T**).

Paragraph 2 says:

> … If **D** appears in the list of parameter declarations of a function definition, let **B** denote the associated block…

So **B** is the block that defines the function.

Paragraph 3 says:

> In what follows, a pointer expression **E** is said to be based on object **P** if (at some sequence point in the execution of **B** prior to the evaluation of **E**) modifying **P** to point to a copy of the array object into which it formerly pointed would change the value of **E**.) Note that "based" is defined only for expressions with pointer types.

So, after `int *a = y + N;`, `a` is based on `y` because modifying `y` prior to this initialization of `a` would change the value of `a`, even if `y` were changed to point to a copy of the array.

Paragraph 4 says:

> During each execution of **B**, let **L** be any lvalue that has **&L** based on **P**. If **L** is used to access the value of the object **X** that it designates, and **X** is also modified (by any means), then the following requirements apply: … Every other lvalue used to access the value of **X** shall also have its address based on **P**…

`*a` is an lvalue **L** that has **&L** based on `y`, because `&*a` is `a`, and we know `a` is based on `y`.

Then, in `*a = 123;`, this **L** is used to access the object it designates, and that object is modified. So the requirements must apply: Every other lvalue used to access the object shall also have its addressed based on `y`.

So, if `*x` also accessed the object designated by `*a`, that would violate the requirement above, because `&*x` is not based on `y`. `x` is passed as a separate parameter, and changing the value of `y` would not change the value of `x`, so `x` and `&*x` are not based on `y`.

Since the compiler is entitled to expect the requirement is met, it may assume that `*a = 123;` does not change `*x`.

Comment: modern compilers treat `restrict` rather as a hint and easily detect the abuse.

Comment: So, IIUC, compiler is allowed to treat all regular pointers that were a result of arbitrary pointer arithmetic on some original `restrict` pointer also as a `restrict` (and to the same "base object", although I'm still unclear whatever it means in this context, i.e. see `f(50, d + 50, d)` example in the std)?

Comment: @DanM.: No. `restrict` is sort of a fence. Declaring `y` as `restrict` puts a fence around it and says other pointers cannot enter that. So the reason `x` cannot refer to an object `y` does is because everything `y` accesses is fenced in. If you had some other pointer `z`, there is nothing that says `x` and `z` cannot refer to the same objects as each other—they are not in y’s fenced area or fenced areas of their own, so they are free to overlap.

Comment: @DanM. https://godbolt.org/z/hz7E53 here you have some code where `restrict` matters (compile without it and see the difference). The compiler detects the abuse of the restrict use.

Comment: @P__J__: Baloney. [Here we see GCC relies on `*x` being 42 after `*a = 123;`.](https://godbolt.org/z/7z3c4G) GCC would have no way of detecting any abuse, as it has no information about the arguments passed for `x` and `y` in this compilation.

Comment: @EricPostpischil yes, that's why I've introduced non-restrict pointer `a` which is "based" on `y` (after some pointer arithmetic), so it could be made to point to the same object as `x`. But your answer suggests that `a` automatically inherits the "fence" of `y` and there is no way around that, so even if the compiler is unable to prove that in some long chain the "seed" value for `a` was `y`, it'll still be UB if it ends up overlapping with `x`.

Comment: actually any use of not restrict pointer in the function voids the the `restrict` in gcc. https://godbolt.org/z/48WPnz

Answer (score 1):

If the value stored to a non-restrict pointer is "based upon" the value of a restrict pointer, then operations using that value are considered to be operations performed upon the original.  This would work out quite intuitively in situations where one pointer or lvalue is definitely based upon a restrict-qualified pointer and another definitely isn't.  Unfortunately, rather than using simple rules for when a pointer is "definitely based upon P" or "definitely not based upon P" another, and allowing for pointers that don't fall into either category (they might be based on P, but can't be proven to be), the Standard instead uses a more complicated rule with absurd, unworkable, and ambiguous corner cases.  This wouldn't be a problem if compilers recognized that a pointer value which is formed from a restrict-qualified pointer in clear and obvious fashion should be regarded as based upon that pointer even in corner cases where the Standard wouldn't require that, but clang and gcc don't treat things that way.

For example, given:

```
int x[1];
int foo(int *restrict p)
{
  *p = 1;
  if (p == x)
  {
    *p = 2;
  }
  return *p;      
}
```

it would seem intuitively obvious that the pointer used in the assignment `*p = 2;` is based upon `restrict p`, but the way the Standard is worded makes that ambiguous.  Replacing `p` with the address of a copy of `*p` would neither result in the assignment being performed to the same address nor to a different address, but for the pointer used in the assignment to be "based upon `p`", such a change to `p` would need to change the address used for the assignment.  Both clang and gcc take the view that preventing an assignment from being performed at all doesn't "change" the address used in that assignment, and thus they don't recognize the pointer used in the assignment `*p = 2;` as having any relationship to `restrict p`.